# Difference between somefile.close and somefile.close()

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

Imagine that you opened some file in Python (it doesn't matter is it for reading, or writing or whatever). I just noticed that when you want to close that file you can type:

```
somefile.close()
```

or you can type:

```
somefile.close
```

Both versions are right and they close file properly. What is the difference (if there is any)?

**Edit: Sentence "Both versions are right and they close file properly." is completely wrong. You can see why in accepted answer.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first useful clue is the result of running both commands in the REPL:

```
>>> f = open("asdf.txt","r")
>>> f.close
<built-in method close of file object at 0x7f38a1da84b0>
>>> f.close()
>>>
```

So `f.close` itself returns a method, that you can then call. For example, you could write:

```
>>> x = f.close
>>> x()
```

To close the file.

So just typing `f.close` isn't actually enough, as it only returns a method that *allows you* to close the file. I can even prove this: go make a file and call it `example.txt`.

Then try out the following code:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open("example.txt","r")
>>> f.close
<built-in method close of file object at 0x7f3d411154b0>
>>> f.readlines()
['this is an example\n', 'file\n']
```

So if we just write `f.close`, we can still use `f.readlines()`: this is proof that the file isn't actually "closed" to access yet!

On the other hand, if we use `f.close()`:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open("example.txt","r")
>>> f.close()
>>> f.readlines()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
>>>
```

So that's proof of the previous assertions: `f.close()` and `f.close` do in fact **not** do the same things. `f.close()` actually closes the file, whereas `f.close` just returns a method to close the file.

---

In this answer, I used Python 2.7.4. I don't know if the behavior of `f.close()` and `f.close` is any different in Python 3+.

Comment: You're completely right. I didn't notice this. But, I wonder now, why f.close doesn't return error. I mean, what is the point (or purpose) of just f.close? When you can use it? Because, doing x = f.close and then x() instead of just f.close() doesn't have any sense. So, when would you (if one will ever) use this?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić Remember that when you call `f.close()`, you are calling an underlying method, the one returned by `f.close`. So this is an "object" on its own, and it makes sense that we should be able to assign it to a variable. It's the same as how if you have a function called **foo()**, you can do things like **x = foo** and then call **x()**. There are some cases in which this might be useful.